# Standard lib flag.intValue does not have String method

Tags: go

```
func (f *FlagSet) IntVar(p *int, name string, value int, usage string) {
    f.Var(newIntValue(value, p), name, usage)
}

func (f *FlagSet) Var(value Value, name string, usage string) {
    flag := &Flag{name, usage, value, value.String()}
    // ...
}

func newIntValue(val int, p *int) *intValue {
    *p = val
    return (*intValue)(p)
}

type intValue int

type Value interface {
    String() string
    Set(string) error
}
```

I read the flag.Int source code, and found:
Standard lib `flag.intValue` does not implements String and Set method, I doesn't found them, how `var value Value = &intValue` works?

(Sorry, my native language is not English.)

Comment: `*intValue` does and that's why `var value Value = &intValue` works.

Comment: But it does, [`flag.go` line #123](https://golang.org/src/flag/flag.go?s=3477:3544#L123)